# Can I toy around learning ASP.NET MVC using only VS 2010 Express and localhost on Windows 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, webserver

If so,

- What tooling do I need?
- What reference sites could be useful?

I have VS 2010 Express, "C# Edition". What is the absolutely most trivial DB and localhost web server setup needed?

(Professionally, I'm a Windows Mobile dev using VS 2008. This ASP.NET MVC task is just for fun at home, to learn something new.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although you should probably use [Visual Web Developer Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) instead.

All you need is SQL CE and Cassini (which are both included in VWD), and the [MVC3 framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3).
For bigger databases, you can use [SQL Server Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/), also free.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to install [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) in addition to [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/). It comes with IIS Express + SQL Compact which is great for "toying".

### Note

You do not need to use WebMatrix IDE, it is only a useful package to install all you need in one go.

Comment: It installs IIS Express and SQL CE.

Comment: Which you don't need.  SQL CE is included with VS (although not v4)